# Error compiling generics with javac but not Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, generics

I have a class that calls one of its own methods internally several times.  All of these methods take a generic parameter (Guava's `Predicate`).  Eclipse compiles this fine and reports no errors and has no warning indicators, with compiler settings set to Java 1.6 compatibility.  Gradle (using JDK 1.6.0_37) reports that one of these times the method is called it cannot find the symbol for that method, but the other times it can.  This seems to involve the use of Guava's `Predicates#and()` static method.  But a similar call with Guava's `Predicates#not()` works.

I have simplified the code down to the following:

```
import static com.google.common.base.Predicates.and;
import static com.google.common.base.Predicates.not;
import com.google.common.base.Predicate;
import com.google.common.base.Predicates;
import com.google.common.collect.FluentIterable;

public class MyClass {
    public List<String> doStuffAnd(List<String> l, Predicate<String> p1, Predicate<String> p2) {
        // eclipse fine, gradle complains it can't find symbol doStuff
        return doStuff(l, and(p1, p2));
    }

    public List<String>  doStuffNot(List<String> l, Predicate<String> p) {
        // both eclipse and gradle compile fine
        return doStuff(l, not(p));
    }

    public List<String> doStuff(List<String> l, Predicate<String> p) {
        return FluentIterable.from(l).filter(p).toList();
    }
}
```

Resulting compile error is:

> doStuff(java.util.List,com.google.common.base.Predicate)
>   in MyClass cannot be applied to
>   (java.util.List,com.google.common.base.Predicate)
>                   return doStuff(l, and(p1, p2));
>                          ^

If I explicitly type the call to `Predicates.and()` as follows

```
return doStuff(l, Predicates.<String>and(p1, p2));
```

then it is fine.  But I don't have to do that with the call to `Predicates.not()`  It also works if I extract the `#and` expression as a local variable.

1. What is the difference between the call using `#and` and the call using `#not`?
2. Is there anything I can do avoid this that involves neither typing the `and` call nor extracting the `and` expression?
3. And why is there a difference between the gradle compiler and Eclipse compiler?

Comment: AFAIK Gradle uses javac, which seems to be less aware of Java generics than Eclipse. Once I even had to do things like `return (Something) (Object) x;` as it claimed that the cast was impossible, though it worked and Eclipse didn't complain at all.

Comment: ad 3. Eclipse ships with its own Java compiler, Gradle uses the JDK Java compiler. It's not uncommon for the two to disagree on finer aspects of the Java language (e.g. generics). Compile class paths can differ as well, as Eclipse and Gradle compute the effective compile class path in different ways.

Comment: Right on the different compilers.  I probably shouldn't have tagged Gradle on this question, but rather Oracle Javac vs Eclipse compiler.  The question is which one is "right"?  Btw, I generate my Eclipse project using Gradle's `eclipse` target.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?  Also there's a good chance that this is fixed in Java 7, you could try upgrading.

Comment: I added the error message to the post

Comment: I pulled your solution out of your question and posted it as a [community wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/147573) answer. Feel free to edit it with additional details if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

*OP's solution*

1. The difference between `and` and `not` is that `and` defines its generic signature for its parameters as `Predicate<? super T>`, whereas `not` uses a simple parameter signature of `Predicate<T>`.
2. So to solve this, I define `doStuffAnd` with parm: `Predicate<? super String>`.